# How to add a handler to a dom element

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var ColorBars = document.getElementsByClassName("color-bar");
    var number = 0;

    ColorBars[0].onclick = hideLine(0);


    function hideLine(index){

        var charts = $("#line-container").highcharts();
        var series = charts.series[index];

        if(series.visible){
            series.hide();
        } else {
            series.show();
        }                        
    }
});
```

If I take out the hideLine(index) and only add

```
 ColorBars[0].onclick = hideLine
```

then it is executing.

I am trying to get all element by their class name and when the user clicks any color bar, I want to know which color bar the user clicked and turn off that chart line in highcharts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ColorBars[0].onclick = hideLine(0);` you are supposed to assign the handler not call it directly

use :

```
ColorBars[0].onclick = function(){
   hideLine(0);
};
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I understood. Solved my problem. Thanks again.